# Из xml передать данные в формулу

Tags: python-3.x, xml

xml выглядит вот так:

```
<item id="31025805">
        <genre>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</genre>
        <type>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</type>
        <source id="31025548">
            <titles>
                <title lang="EN">CEUR Workshop Proceedings</title>
            </titles>
            <titleaddinfo>3</titleaddinfo>
            <volumenumber>1825</volumenumber>
            <volumename>MMIT 2016 - Proceedings of 3rd Russian Conference "Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies"</volumename>
            <seriesname>MMIT 2016 - Proceedings of 3rd Russian Conference "Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies"</seriesname>
            <yearpubl>2016</yearpubl>
            <confname>3rd Russian Conference "Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies", MMIT 2016</confname>
            <confplace>Yekaterinburg</confplace>
            <confdatebegin>16.11.2016</confdatebegin>
        </source>
        <pages>111-117</pages>
        <language>IT</language>
        <yearpubl>2016</yearpubl>
        <cited>0</cited>
        <titles>
            <title lang="EN">Modelling of cash flows by means of Markov processes</title>
        </titles>
        <grnti>270100</grnti>
        <risc>yes</risc>
        <corerisc>yes</corerisc>
        <authors>
            <author num="1" lang="EN">
                <lastname>Timofeeva</lastname>
                <initials>G.A.</initials>
                <authorid>15676</authorid>
                <spin>2292-7833</spin>
                <email>Gtimofeeva@usurt.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Ural State University of Railway Transport</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>rus</country>
                        <town>Yekaterinburg</town>
                    </affiliation>
                    <affiliation num="2" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
                        <orgid>290</orgid>
                        <country>rus</country>
                        <town>Yekaterinburg</town>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
            <author num="2" lang="EN">
                <lastname>Bozhalkina</lastname>
                <initials>Y.A.</initials>
                <authorid>779136</authorid>
                <spin>6791-5486</spin>
                <email>Bozhalkina@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Ural State University of Railway Transport</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>rus</country>
                        <town>Yekaterinburg</town>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
        </authors>
    </item>
    <item id="29099767">
        <genre>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</genre>
        <type>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</type>
        <source id="29091999">
            <titles>
                <title lang="EN">Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies</title>
                <title lang="RU">Математическое моделирование и информационные технологии</title>
            </titles>
            <titleaddinfo>Proceedings</titleaddinfo>
            <yearpubl>2016</yearpubl>
            <pagesnumber>275</pagesnumber>
            <publisher>CEUR-WS.org</publisher>
            <confname>3rd Russian Conference "Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies"</confname>
            <confplace>Екатеринбург</confplace>
            <confdatebegin>16.11.2016</confdatebegin>
            <confdateend>16.11.2016</confdateend>
        </source>
        <pages>111-117</pages>
        <language>RU</language>
        <yearpubl>2016</yearpubl>
        <cited>0</cited>
        <titles>
            <title lang="RU">Моделирование потоков платежей с помощью марковских случайных процессов</title>
        </titles>
        <grnti>270100</grnti>
        <risc>yes</risc>
        <corerisc>no</corerisc>
        <authors>
            <author num="1" lang="EN">
                <lastname>Timofeeva</lastname>
                <initials>G.A.</initials>
                <authorid>15676</authorid>
                <spin>2292-7833</spin>
                <email>Gtimofeeva@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Public Educational Institution of Higher Professional Education The Ural State University of Railway Transport</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>RUS</country>
                        <town>Ekaterinburg</town>
                        <address>Kolmogorov Street 66, Ekaterinburg, Russia, 620034</address>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
            <author num="1" lang="RU">
                <lastname>Тимофеева</lastname>
                <initials>Галина Адольфовна</initials>
                <authorid>15676</authorid>
                <spin>2292-7833</spin>
                <email>Gtimofeeva@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="RU">
                        <orgname>Уральский государственный университет путей сообщения</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>RUS</country>
                        <town>Екатеринбург</town>
                        <address>620034  г.Екатеринбург, ул. Колмогорова,66</address>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
            <author num="2" lang="EN">
                <lastname>Bozhalkina</lastname>
                <initials>Ya.A.</initials>
                <authorid>779136</authorid>
                <spin>6791-5486</spin>
                <email>bozhalkina@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Public Educational Institution of Higher Professional Education The Ural State University of Railway Transport</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>RUS</country>
                        <town>Ekaterinburg</town>
                        <address>Kolmogorov Street 66, Ekaterinburg, Russia, 620034</address>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
            <author num="2" lang="RU">
                <lastname>Божалкина</lastname>
                <initials>Яна Андреевна</initials>
                <authorid>779136</authorid>
                <spin>6791-5486</spin>
                <email>bozhalkina@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="RU">
                        <orgname>Уральский государственный университет путей сообщения</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>RUS</country>
                        <town>Екатеринбург</town>
                        <address>620034  г.Екатеринбург, ул. Колмогорова,66</address>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
        </authors>
    </item>
```

Из xml получаю ФИО авторов в таком виде:

```
['<lastname>Овчинников</lastname> <initials>Игорь Георгиевич</initials>', '<lastname>Овчинников</lastname> <initials>Илья Игоревич</initials>', '<lastname>Телегин</lastname> <initials>Максим Александрович</initials>', '<lastname>Хохлов</lastname> <initials>Сергей Викторович</initials>']
```

Или вот в таком:

```
['<lastname>Овчинников</lastname> <initials>И.Г.</initials>', '<lastname>Овчинников</lastname> <initials>И.И.</initials>', '<lastname>Караханян</lastname> <initials>А.Б.</initials>']
```

За каждым автором закреплен индивидуальный код. Я оформила его в виде двух словарей(с инициалами, с полным именем). Например, полное имя:

```
full_name_auth = {'Овчинников Игорь Георгиевич': '10002712', 'Алексеева Людмила Модестовна': '10000006', 'Анненкова Капитолина Ивановна': '10000007'}
```

Или ФИО с инициалами:

```
ini_name = {'Овчинников И. Г.': '10002712', 'Алексеева Л. М.': '10000006', 'Анненкова К. И.': '10000007'}
```

Индивидуальный код у авторов и в том, и в другом словаре абсолютно одинаковый.
Если у статьи автор один, то он должен попасть в формулу со своим кодом в таком виде:

```
#700: ^310002712^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.
```

Если авторов 2, то первый встает в 700 поле, а второй в 701. Выглядит вот так:

```
#700: ^310002712^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.
#701: ^AШепелева^BИ. О.
```

Если авторов нет в словарях, то он будет без кода. Если авторов 3, то:

```
#700: ^310002712^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.
#701: ^310000006^AАлексеева^BЛ. М.
#701: ^AГузенкова^BЕ. А.
```

Если 4 и больше, то авторы все попадают в 701:

```
#701: ^310002712^AОвчинников^BИ. Г.
#701: ^AСтаценко^BК. А.
#701: ^AГузенкова^BЕ. А.
#701: ^AПахомов^BА. П.
```

Я решила авторов посчитать и коды подставляла в ручную. Мой вариант непрактичный и, мало того, длиннющий получился и работает только для одного автора. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне автоматизировать этот процесс. Заранее благодарна за ответ.
P.S. Вчера я уже задавала подобный вопрос и мне понравилось решение, но теперь я не могу сообразить как решить вопрос с количеством авторов. Благодарю за понимание

Comment: А как у вас выглядит информация о статье, где пишутся авторы?

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev, добавила xml

Comment: Тогда, как решение, вы можете пробегать по всем `author` и находить максимальный `value` в `num = %value%`. А дальше уже отталкиваться от этого. Или считать количество `<author>` в `<authors>`

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev, благодарю Вас за отклик. Но я не совсем поняла. Например, я посчитаю авторов. Если автор 1 ставим 700 поле, если 2, то 700, потом 701 и т.д. Это я сделала. Но как мне каждой фамилии код присвоить? Вот это я понять не могу

Comment: А у вас авторы участвуют только в одной книге и не более? Если в нескольких, то как вообще однозначно можно объявить им ключ, если каждый ключ зависит от книги

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev, авторы могут участвовать в нескольких публикациях. Ключ = ФИО автора, значение = код автора(в цифрах). Код автора не меняется. Я себе представляю это так........Программа распознает в списке авторов публикации нужного человека и вставляет в формулу его код(значение в цифрах из словаря(того или иного))

Comment: А если у автора много книг и у него где 701, а где 700 получается. Как вносить?

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev, не у автора много книг, а у публикации несколько авторов может быть, а может быть только один. Если автор один, то в 700 поле. Если автора 2, то первый в 700, а второй в 701. Если авторов 3, то первый в 700, второй и третий в 701. А если их 4 и больше, то все в 701

Comment: Я вам про одно, вы мне про другое. Как быть, если автор в двух книгах. В одной у него 700 код, а во второй 701. Что записывать?

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev, это не важно. Главное один автор в 700, а остальные в 701(если авторов: 1, 2 или 3). Если авторов 4 и больше все в 701